# Linked list delete largest

Tags: c, list

```
 typedef struct _node *Node;
 typedef struct _list *List;

typedef struct _list {
    Node head;
} list;

typedef struct _node {
    int value;
    Node next;
} node; 


int listDeleteLargest(List l) {
     Node meme = l->head;
     int largest = meme->value;
     while (meme != NULL) {
         if (largest < meme->value) {
             largest = meme->value;
         }
         meme = meme->next;
      }


Node prev = l->head;
Node temp = prev->next;
Node current = prev->next;


while (current != NULL) {
        if (prev->value == largest) {
            temp = prev;
            prev = prev->next;
            l->head = prev;
            free(temp);
        } else if (current->value == largest) {
                if (current->next == NULL) {
                    prev->next = NULL;
                    temp = current;
                    free(temp);
                } else {
                    prev->next = current->next;
                    current = current->next;
                    temp = current;
                    free(temp);
                }
        }
    current = current->next;   //runtime error here
    }
return 0;
}



//the struct typedef here.
```

For this code, I'm trying to delete the largest. The logic seems right but i keep getting a runtime error during current = current->next;

For example, if there are two large numbers in the linked list, it'll delete both. I wrote the code on the account that it caters for if the node is at the end, the end and the rest. I've run my tests but I still can't see why it wont compile properly.

Comment: `free(temp);` also frees `current` and since you don't change the address `current` points at you are dereferencing an invalid location (invoking *undefined behavior*)

Comment: _"i keep getting a runtime error"_ which is?

Comment: Important: `free(ptr)` does NOT "free the pointer". This would be point(badumdish)less anyway. What you're freeing is the memory the pointer is pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

If `current->value != largest`, you end up doing `current = current->next` twice, and risk running off the end of the list.

Also, this code:

```
temp = current;
free(temp);
```

will delete `current`, because both `temp` and `current` will be pointing at the same thing.

Comment: Hey sorry im still not sure what is wrong with it I still keep getting the same error.

Comment: Nevermind! I understand it now. Since I was freeing (current) in the loop and not exiting by return 0;, the current == NULL when it reached the current= current->next function